# When did self-balancing binary search trees become known outside the soviet union?

Tags: ho.history-overview, binary-trees

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), the AVL tree was first published in 1962 by Soviet scientists Adelson-Velsky and Landis.  The earliest self-balancing binary search tree I can find by a non-soviet block scientist is the red-black tree, created by West German computer scientist Rudolf Bayer in 1972.

My questions are:

1. Did Bayer and other non-Soviets know about the AVL tree (or any other self-balancing binary search tree) at this point in time?
2. When did the AVL tree become known to non-Soviet researchers?  And in particular, when was it translated into English?
3. I can't find copies of the original publications online for these papers, but I'd like to read them for their references.  Can anyone help me find copies?

Comment: 2 and 3 are answered by reference [3] in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: ...and 1 can be answered by looking at the technical report version of the paper introducing B-trees, which is linked from the Wikipedia article on B-tree. The answer is yes, they were aware of it, since they cite it. For this kind of question, it can also help to go to a university library (in case this is feasible for you) and browse through the academic journal volumes if googling does not help.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks!  Don't know how I missed that.  To fully answer my title question, then, I need to know whether the AVL tree was the first self-balancing binary search tree.  Based on the paper, I'm guessing yes since they don't cite any prior work, but that could just be because they didn't know about it.